# PowerShell Script from batchfile

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript

1. I need to make a script that can stop a certain process (VPN connection) through the name or id.
2. Since this requires Administrator rights, I can't seem to find a solution in .bat file, so i've made a .bat file, that points on the ps1. file, that calls the executionpolicy and the file.
3. But during the process PowerShell makes a popup asking for a Y/N answer to kill the process.

Can I please have a solution where it forces a Y so I don't need to see that PS box all the time?

My .bat file:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted','-File C:\Scripts\IPsecStopProcess.ps1' -Verb RunAs"
```

If there is another way to make the process stop, I'll listen to all solutions you guyz and girlz can come up with?

Comment: Since the issue is in your ps1 script, can you post the contents?

Comment: My ps1 file only contains:
Stop-Process -id 20804

Answer (score 0):

You're best off doing all your tasks in PowerShell, instead of calling different scripts.

Use the '-Force' parameter with 'Stop-Process'. Have a read of this article for more information: [Stop-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process?view=powershell-6)